# pandas read_csv with chunksize

Tags: pandas

```
# calculate CTR
count_all = 0
count_4 = 0
for df in pd.read_csv( open("%s/tianchi_fresh_comp_train_user.csv" % 
root_path,'r'), chunksize=10000):
     try:
         count_user = df['behavior_type'].value_counts()
         count_all += count_user[1]+count_user[2]+count_user[3]+count_user[4]
         count_4 += count_user[4]
     except StopIteration:
         print("Iteration is stopped.")

# CTR
print(count_all)
print(count_4)
```

**Error Information**

[image]

but if I modify `chunksize` from 10000 to 100000.
      `chunksize  = 100000`,
it is OK, no problem

why, I set `chunksize = 10000`, have error?

Comment: The thing here is when you do chunk 1000, some chunk file will not include behavior_type 4

Comment: yes,you are right. but how to solve this problem? should i check every chunk whether they have 1,or 2, or 3,or 4??

Answer (score 0):

```
count_all = 0
count_4 = 0
for df in pd.read_csv( open("%s/tianchi_fresh_comp_train_user.csv" % root_path,'r'), 
chunksize=10000):
    try:
        count_user = df['behavior_type'].value_counts()
        for i in range(5):
            if i not in count_user.index: count_user[i] = 0
            else:
               count_all += count_user[i]
        count_4 += count_user[4]
    except StopIteration:
          print("Iteration is stopped.")
```

i modify the code, now it is ok,when chunksize=10000,no problem.